# How can i make numpy work( it shows symbol not found)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, ipython

when I used ipython and when i tried to import numpy 
python says:

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2):
>   Symbol not found: _PyBuffer_Type   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so   Expected
>   in: flat namespace  in
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so

what should I do? 
I have already downloaded python 3.6 on my computer. But it is still referencing to python 2.7.

Comment: How do you execute this code? Through terminal or through an IDE? If through terminal you have to use `python3 <file>.py`

Comment: How do you install numpy and ipython?